# Insert barcode decode data(13 digit number) into SQL Server with webcam using python

Tags: python, sql-server

Python + SQL Server

I am using my webcam to decode real time barcode. First I tried to save the decoded barcode in text file it is working fine. Than I established a successfull connection between Python and SQL Server than I have created a database with name "sample_data_barcode" and table "data" and my primary key is "product_id" which is auto incremented and "product_no" is 13 digit barcode number which I am trying to decode and insert in SQL Server but it is not inserting .

Code:

```
    driver= '{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}'
    
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
        Trusted_Connection='Yes',
        Driver='{ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server}',
        Server='DESKTOP-JI50OFV\SQLEXPRESS',
        Database='sample_data_barcode'
    )
    cursor=cnxn.cursor()
    def read_barcodes(frame):
        barcodes = pyzbar.decode(frame)
        for barcode in barcodes:
            x, y , w, h = barcode.rect
            #1
            barcode_info = barcode.data.decode('utf-8')
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y),(x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            
            #2
            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
            cv2.putText(frame, barcode_info, (x + 6, y - 6), font, 2.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)
            #3
            #with open("barcode_result.txt", mode ='w') as file:
            #    file.write("Recognized Barcode:" + barcode_info)
            
            cursor.execute('insert into data(product_no) values(?);',(barcode_info))
            #rows=cursor.fetchall()
        return frame
```

Comment: `SQL Server Native Client 11.0` and `ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server` are both quite old and basically unsupported. Is your SQL Server modern enough to support [ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server)?

Comment: Have you read up on the [connection.autocommit](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connection#autocommit) property? It may be rolling back your insert operation for you.